# Getting a reference to data collected by a Service from an Activity for visualization purposes

Tags: android

Hello fellow developers,

I am trying to achieve something in Android and I would like some advise on the best practice.

I have created an Activity which can start and stop a Service which collects data.

Instead of simply starting and stopping the Service, the Activity should also display the data collected by the Service.

Here in lies the problem. The data could be quite large so I would like to avoid Serializing and sending it via an Intent. Is it possible to simply get a reference to the data stored in the Service from the Activity?

**Simple Example**

1) Activity starts

2) Activity starts Service to collect data

3) Activity exists

4) 24 hours pass

5) Activity starts

6) Activity wants to display data collected by Service, but data is quite large.

My question again is simply this. Can the Activity get a reference to the data stored in Service or does the data have to be Serialized and sent from the Service to the Activity using an Intent?

Kind regards,
Cathal

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Research `android.app.Application` class. Essentially you can use this for global state.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Application.html

Also, any long term data should be stored to a local database. I would try to limit the SELECT to certain number of records to reduce memory footprint.

Comment: >> Also, any long term data should be stored to a local database.
This is my next step.

Thank you for your quick response.

Answer (score 0):

I've heard that the Application class should not be used in this way necessarily (via Google Team). Instead you could make a separate Singleton class (For example call it "MyData") that holds a public static reference to a let's say ArrayList (For example called "list_data").

So when he activity starts it will call

```
MyData.list_data = new ArrayList<MyDataObj>();
```

Then in your Service you can add all of your data objects to this static arraylist like so:

```
MyData.list_data.add(new MyDataObj());
```

This allows you to work off of the same ArrayList without passing it around using Intents and etc. Although I would suggest doing some null checking whenevr